# Query related to Facebook post using graph.facebook.com API

Tags: facebook

We are using following Facebook graph API for fetching posts information for facebook application "LuxIndi"

https://graph.facebook.com/LuxIndia/posts

This API returns all the post of this application which is posted by author of this application. Is this correct?

If user put his own post in this application then this API does not return that post.
So If I need to get all the post posted by all the users in this application which is the API I can use?

Please see following facebook application to understand this issue.

https://www.facebook.com/LuxIndia

Thanks & regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 0):

Posts will give you posts from Page owner where as feed will give you all posts made on the page including users and owner.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/LuxIndia/feed
```

you can also play with limit parameter like shown below

```
https://graph.facebook.com/LuxIndia/feed?limit=100
```

Try result on Facebook Developers > tools > Graph API Explorer